# Find the force used to press a book against a leaned desk so it doesn't slip

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

I know there are several threads concerning this issue, but none of it helped me, so I decided to open a new one.

So, the task is to find a force $F_{\mathrm{push}}$ on a desk which is leaned for an angle of $\varphi=45^{\circ}$

I know that for a vertical system you calculate that $F_{\mathrm{push}}=F_{\mathrm{friction}}=k F_{\mathrm{\mathrm{normal}}}$ and that's how it is calculated, but for this particular case I do not know...

I also know that $F_{\mathrm{static}} = mg\cos(\varphi)$ and $F_{\mathrm{dynamic}} = mg\sin(\varphi)$, so I guess that the $F_{\mathrm{friction}} = -kmg\cos(\varphi)$

Please help me, are any of these formulas correct?

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, you have a desk leaning at 45 degrees with a book resting on the desk, and you want to know the force the book applies on the desk, correct? If so, instead breaking the force into x and y components break it into components that are parallel and normal to the desk. The normal component will be your force on the desk. Since the only force on your system that has a component normal to the desk is gravity, your job is to essentially find the force of gravity perpendicular to the surface of the desk. The normal force will be equal and opposite this.

Comment: no, I press it with my hand so it doesn't slip down the desk

Comment: and how this relates to conservation of energy? http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_04.html

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify in what direction the force of hand is applied, so for simplicity I assume that you are applying the force perpendicular to the desk.

Now there are four forces on the book: 1) Gravity ($mg$) is trying to take the book down; it has a component $mg\cos\theta$ that is perpendicular to the desk and a component $mg\sin\theta$ that is parallel to the desk. 2) The normal force from the desk ($N$) perpendicular to the desk. 3) The force of hand ($F$) perpendicular to the desk. 4) Friction ($f$) which is parallel to the desk and is trying to oppose the $mg\sin\theta$ component of gravity.

The sum of forces perpendicular to the desk should be zero, hence $F+mg\cos\theta = N$. If the book is not to fall, the sum of forces parallel to the desk should also be zero, hence $f=mg\sin\theta$. Now comes the relation between static friction and the normal force $f_s\le \mu_s N$, where $\mu_s$ is [the coefficient of static friction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction#Coefficient_of_friction).

Combining the three equations in the above paragraph you find $mg\sin\theta\le \mu_s F+\mu_s mg\cos\theta$, or

\begin{equation}
mg\sin\theta/\mu_s - mg\cos\theta \le F.
\end{equation}

Therefore the minimum force of hand you need to exert perpendicular to the desk on the book to keep it from sliding down is $F_{\text{min}}=mg\sin\theta/\mu_s - mg\cos\theta$.